# PHP Includes not loading in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, include

We have a site that we have built in WordPress that is having some issues.  When you land on the home page of the site there are certain `include` files that do not load upon first landing on the page and it also happens intermittently throughout viewing this page.  I would like to know it there is a good way to debug these includes (no errors in PHP log) or what best practice would be to trace down this issue.  I am at a loss.

I know WP hooks are recommended over includes but this theme was passed off to us using hooks.

Note: Firebug Console does not provide any errors.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated, I am lost with this one.

Comment: Firebug is client side so i don't think it will be much help.  Do you have a sample of the code?  There really isn't much to go off here without seeing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a memory problem with PHP. Try increasing PHP's memory_limit setting to 64M. Put the following inside .htaccess:

`php_value memory_limit 64M`

Also validate your HTML and see if there are any errors like unclosed divs.
Check your javascripts for anything that can remove parts of your content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it using something like xdebug to give you a better idea of what is going on.

An easier alternative would be to turn error reporting on so you can see what is happening on page rather than trawling through error logs:

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

Put those at the top of load.php

Comment: I have this enabled.  No help, no errors are being logged or shown